# django programming error : column does not exist

Tags: django, docker, django-models, migration, backend

Hello I am running a django app using Django. The app is working correctly . But when I add a new field in my model.py I got this error

ProgrammingError at /admin/challenges/challenge/
column challenge.category does not exist
LINE 1: ..., "challenge"."modified_at", "challenge"."title", "challenge...

I found similar questions but they didn't solve my problem.
I tried to run "python manage.py migrate" and it doesn't solve the problem

Could any one help me please ?

Comment: have you done makemigrations

Comment: Yes I have done makemigrations and migrate

Comment: If you run showmigrations does it shows your newly created migration with a check?

Comment: I am running the app with docker containers and the migrate and makemigrations commands are run automatically when I run : docker-compose up --build

Comment: Ok, you can still access the shell to check the state of the db. I think that running `./compose.sh run --rm <backend_container_name> python manage.py shell` lets you access the shell (replace <backend_container_name> with the correct value). Then you can run `python manage.py showmigrations` and see if the migration has been applied.

Comment: The problem is solved by running :python manage.py makemigrations and   python manage.py makemigrations from the shell terminal but to access it I used  : docker exec -ti <backend_container_name> /bin/bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have not done make migration command. Perform

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

and then use command

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: They are run automatically when I run . docker-compose up --build .  So it doesn't seem to be a migration problem